# Grub rescue unknown file system error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue, grub-legacy

I formatted my partition of Ubuntu 11.04 and created a new simple volume in Windows. But when I rebooted my laptop, I got an error `:no such partition`.

I tried nearly all commands suggested, but could not find a way out.

When I type `ls` it shows:

```
(hd0),(hd0,msdos7),(hd0,msdos6),(hd0,msdos5),(hd0,msdos3),(hd0,msdos2),(hd0,msdos1)
```

When I use any of them with `ls` command individually, I'm returned unknown file system error.

When I tried setting each one as a prefix and root I had problem with `insmod`.

When I try to use `insmod`, I'm prompted with error: unknown filesystem. I've tried setting either of these as prefix and then root, but whenever I try to `insmod` I'm prompted with the same error: unknown filesystem.

Comment: Insert windows cd/dvd and perform repair.

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot the Windows 7 installer and then go to "Repair your computer" [image]
Then select the 1st option "Startup repair", this should automatically repair your boot partition and run Windows 7, the grub will not appear any more. [image]

Comment: Corrected the spelling for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. create a ubuntu bootable USB,
2. then launch ubuntu from the USB,
3. launch ubuntu terminal
4. write :

`sudo apt-get install syslinux`

`sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`

To create a bootable USB : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
To launch ubuntu from the usb, press F11 or F12 when your computer boot (before windows start).
To launch ubuntu terminal  Ctrl - Alt + T